# Always same culture: en-US

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core project where I want to set the default language to nl-BE. For some reason it always take the language en-US

See code below (ps: I created my own ApplicationLocalizer who fetched the resources from a database => works fine).

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            //Add MVC
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization();

            //Localization factory
            services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, ApplicationLocalizerFactory>();

            ...
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
            ...

            //Localization
            var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("nl-BE")
                };
            var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nl-BE"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options);

            ...
}
```

**A controller**

```
public string Index()
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
}
```

This snippet of code always returns **en-US**

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: your code looks ok, I suspect that even though the default culture is not en-US that your web browser language preference is set to en-US therefore it uses that since it is supported. make sure also you don't have a cookie set with a language pref of en-US. I once had a localhost cookie like that from playing with a localization sample, so clearing the cookies might help

Comment: Thxs for the reply. I already changed the browser language to nl-BE and erased all cookies but it keeps on taking en-US language

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching for solution with no result, I went for heavy debugging and realized that the middleware services are executed in an **order** as declared in the **Configure(IApplicationBuilder app...)**. Therefore the localization middleware was invoked **after** the controller action was executed.

When I moved the *app.UseRequestLocalization(options)* invocation at the very beginning I got properly localized Thread/CultureInfo in controller actions.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // THIS HAS TO BE A VERY FIRST MIDDLEWARE REGISTRATION
        SetUpLocalization(app);

        app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

        app.UseMvc();

        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
    }

    private static void SetUpLocalization(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("pl-PL"),
            new CultureInfo("pl")
        };

        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        };
        // Configure the Localization middleware
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
```

Comment: Just got the same issue, i would never think about the calling order! Thanks