# Localization Returning the name only and not the value from the resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For Some Reason, my localization setup in asp.net core 3.1 is only returning the name not the value of the string. Its showing that its not found for some reason even though I have the resource file name as such.

```
namespace RoundTableERP.Controllers
{
public class StockController : Controller
{
    private  readonly IStringLocalizer<StockController> _localizer;

    RoundTableAPIClient apiClient = new RoundTableAPIClient();
    // GET

    public StockController(IStringLocalizer<StockController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;

    }
    public IActionResult Index()  
    {


        ViewBag.Title = _localizer[ResourceKeys.StockPageTitle];

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I looked at my searched location I see that it's returning not found. But its also giving me this path

ResourceKeys is just a file with the value i want retrieved from my resource file

ResourceKeys

Element inside my xml resource file

```
<data name="StockPageTitle" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>This should be the title in english</value>
 </data>
```

> RoundTableWeb.Erp.Resources.RoundTableERP.Controllers.StockController

But as you see I have this done here. Its set to be embedded but when I look at the properties of the localizer it's showing not found. I installed the tag helpers and the other localization nuggets as suggested by other so questions but still, it returns only the name.

My Startup cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
            // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);
        //lets inject the connection string to the data layer 
        //but we should be using the api layer for any heavy lifting.
        services.AddHttpClient("externalservice", c =>
        {
            // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
        });

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {new CultureInfo("en-GB"), new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),};

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");

            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
        services.AddKendo();
}
```

This is my configure section

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

        app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
    }
```

[image]

When I look at the localizer element it is showing NotFound

[image]

You can see a short video of my problem here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DaKvRlM9iRS5_1zvJjqTZlOE16UhhE6r/view

Answer (score 0):

Move the `app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value)` to the very beginning of middleware pipeline instead of after `app.UseEndpoints()`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    //other middlewares
}
```

Refer to [Always same culture: en-US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997851/always-same-culture-en-us)

***Update 12/26/2019***

It turns out that your `StockController` has namespace `RoundTableERP.Controllers` which leads to the `SearchedLocation` as `RoundTableWeb.Erp.Resources.RoundTableERP.Controllers.StockController`.

There are two solutions:

1) Change `StockController` namespaces to `Controllers` or `RoundTableWeb.Erp.Controllers`, this will leads to  `SearchedLocation` as `RoundTableWeb.Erp.Resources.Controllers.StockController`

2) If you do not want to change the controller namespace, change the name of recourse file to `RoundTableERP.Controllers.StockController.en-gb.resx` under `Resources` folder directly

Also remember to put `app.UseRequestLocalization` at the very beginning of middleware pipeline.

Comment: Its not the same culture its simply not finding it but will try what you said

Comment: This didnt work for me its still only showing the key not the actual value

Comment: Your `SearchedLocation` have extra `RoundTableERP`.You need to change your controller namespace or change your resource file name.See my edit.

Comment: this still does not work using the documentation on microsoft web site.